# How to calculate user age from birth year till registration date using Django ORM

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models

i have a model which contains a field birth_year and in another model i have the user registration date.
I have the list of user ids for which i want to query if their age belongs to a particular range of age.User age is calculated as registration date - birth_year.

I was able to calculate it from current date as:

```
startAge=25
endAge=50
ageStartRange = (today - relativedelta(years=startAge)).year
ageEndRange = (today - relativedelta(years=endAge)).year
```

and i made the query as:

```
query.filter(profile_id__in=communityUsersIds, birth_year__lte=age_from, birth_year__gte=age_to).values('profile_id')
```

This way i am getting the userids whose age is in range bw 25 and 50. Instead of today how can i use registration_date(it is a field in another model) of user.

Comment: Can update it with models.py

Answer (score 3):

You can use native DB functions. Works like a charm using Postgres.

```py
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models import DurationField, IntegerField, F, Func


class Age(Func):
    function = 'AGE'
    output_field = DurationField()


class AgeYears(Func):
    template = 'EXTRACT (YEAR FROM %(function)s(%(expressions)s))'
    function = 'AGE'
    output_field = IntegerField()


users = User.objects.annotate(age=Age(F("dob")), age_years=AgeYears(F("dob"))).filter(age_years__gte=18)
for user in users:
    print(user.age, user.age_years)

# which will generate result like below
# 10611 days, 0:00:00 29
```

Answer (score 2):

The "today" version of the query was easy to do, because the "today" date doesn't depend on the individual fields in the row.

### F Expressions

You can explore Django's F expressions as they allow you to reference the fields of the model in your queries (without pulling them into Python)

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/queries/#using-f-expressions-in-filters

e.g. for you, the *age* would be this F expressions:

`F('registration_date__year') - F('birth_year')`

However, we don't *really* need to calculate that, because e.g. to query for what you want, consider this query:

```
Model.filter(birth_year__lte=F('regisration_date__year') - 25)
```

From that you can do add a:

`birth_year__gte=F('regisration_date__year') + 50`,

or use a `birth_year__range=(F('regisration_date__year') - 25, F('regisration_date__year') + 50))`

### Alternative: precalculate *age* value

Otherwise you can precalculate that *age*, since that value is knowable on user registration time

```
Model.update(age=F('registration_date__year') - F('birth_year'))
```

Once that is saved, it's as simple as `Model.filter(age__range=(25, 50))`

Comment: great. Thanx. I will just quickly look F expressions.

Comment: No problem, I tried to put in sample filter queries, I may have inverted the polarity of the `lte` and `gte` comparison queries, but I hope you get the idea!

Comment: If there are only birth year your approach is ok. But if full date of birth can be fetched then the following case could happen: user birth date is 2000.12.31, registration date is 2015.01.01. The result will be 15 years, but the actual result is 14 years and 2 days. Be careful using this approach if you need full years.